# How can we add sticker to default keyboard in android

Tags: java, android, emoji, custom-keyboard

I want to add some special my own stickers to the default/builtin keyboard of android so that everyone can use it from any platform like messaging, WhatsApp and FB etc. I am searching for a couple of weeks but I never found any relevant solution. Is there any solution? Can I develop such app which could forcefully add the stickers to the default keyboard of every android mobile?

Comment: There's no such thing as "builtin keyboard of android", most manufacturers have their own keyboards they set as default. And users can add their own keyboards on top of it. And pretty much every keyboard has its own API for plugins, and generally don't allow some unrelated app to "force" something into them (because allowing any external code to force things into users keyboards is how you get your users passwords stolen).

Comment: thanks for your response. Actually here force means our app should work as a plugin that adds stickers into the user keyboard.

Comment: What kind of keyboard? Pretty sure each one has its own format for plugins, and some don't allow plugins at all.

Comment: Reminder to reviewers that "question asks how to do something that is clearly described, but impossible" is not a reason to close a question.  "This is not possible" is an answer.

Comment: i think andorid will not allow you to play that much with its keyboard, but if you badly want it you can create your own keyboard for your app, you can easily found numbers of codes for custom keyboar on github.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.

There's not a standard "default Android keyboard" (it's up to the individual device makers), nor is there any API in the Android platform to supply stickers to keyboards.  It is possible that individual keyboards could implement such an API (though I'm not personally aware of any), but there is no standard platform API that would work across all keyboards with such support.